# What's the proper way to implement FindControl

Tags: asp.net, webforms, telerik

Sorry in advance for the long question.

Since I'm running into StackOverflow exceptions (ironically), which i know the cause of, i am really wondering whether i've got my concept, of how to implement FindControl right.

My idea was, that if you're implementing a custom child control collection, which should be accessible to FindControl, you'd have to implement FindControl and search through your list in addition to calling the base method.

So this is the situation now:
I wrote a Server Control, which has a templateproperty (which i'm adding on init). Let's call that "panel" for now (It's not the default asp one)

My structure is along the lines of this:

```
panel (1)
 panel (2)
  telerik:RadTabStrip
 panel (3)
  telerik:RadMultiPage
```

Now prior to my change finding controls worked ok, with the exception that if the radTabStrip would look for the multipage through its id it would start looking in 2, where it obviously can't find the other multipage, since it's not a direct child of 2.

My change was to go to the NamingContainer (leads to 3) and loop through the child controls and execute FindControl there. This initially worked to solve this issue.

However in a structure where there was 3 children and the desired control was the third this way of searching would result in dancing back and forth between the first and the second panel. So it's a sibling search which triggered the StackOverflowException, which makes sense.

Apparently however this raised the question for me if i'm not actually doing something terribly wrong there. Other controls seem to have no trouble looking through hierarchies of NamingContainers without any hassle.

Is there some ID name register (e.g. all controls within naming container register their contained id's and in findcontrol you'd just go to some look up class to find the control you want without any custom logic to navigate through controls and calling FindControl) I'm not aware of, or something alike?

I really hope you can help me with this one.

I have an idea how to solve my issue for this problem, but I'd love to know how to actually do this the way it's supposed to be done correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each Control has its own Controls collection, that is 'built in' - you do not need a 'naming register'.

You basically need a recursive function:
Write, for example, `MyFindControl` so that it accepts a Control-Collection as a parameter. 
Have your function iterate through that collection, and if you find the control (by name?) you're looking for, return it.

And if the control you're currently checking is not the one you're looking for, let your function call itself again, giving that control's control collection as a parameter.

If the control that is being searched does not turn up, you can return `Nothing` or `Null` (depending on your language), or you can raise an error. The code using your custom FindControl implementation must handle that.

Comment: this would not resolve the problem of beeing unable to find controls in parent/sibling hierarchies though. recursing through children is not the situation i'm having problems with - that would be rather easy and generic to fix.

Comment: You could write a helper method like `GetParent` which goes all the way up to the highest instance (e.g., the Master Page), then iterate through the controls with the above (yes, very basic and generic) method.

Comment: So what you're saying is that the problem is that i'm working with the implementation of other controls for FindControl which in turn leads to infinite recursion. I'm sure that would work, but it seems like an awful lot of control traversal and would only work for controls exposed by the Controls property. FindControl usually offers searching for Controls which are not exposed by the Controls property.

That's why i went for that and why it somehow doesn't feel right for me.

Comment: Maybe there is a whole different approach. WHY do you need to find a control in that scenario?

Comment: in the markup i showed panel (2) contains a tabstrip. upon clicking that it will go back on the server and attempt to find a pageview within the multipage inside panel (3) through the use of FindControl on it's naming container. since the naming container returned to start the search panel(2) is beeing used and the path required to find it is going to panel (1), call FindControl there to get to panel (3). However since the panel browses through its child controls that will end up in infinite recursion. (I've solved the problem in the meantime. But i'm sure there has to be a better way)